# How to save PDF in database with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm generating PDF of html table. I want to save pdf in database. This script is downloading pdf. I want to send pdf file to controller side then save in database. I'm getting base64 string in controller now how i can save with url?

```
 var doc = new jsPDF({
       unit: 'px',
       format: 'a4'
 });

    doc.fromHTML($('#revision_table').get(0), 2, 2);
    doc.save('scdedule_revision.pdf');
    var pdf = doc.output();

    axios.post(this.$path + 'api/savePdf', null,
           {
              params: {'pdf_file':  doc.output('datauri')}          
           }
    ).then(({data}) => (
           console.log(data)
         ))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Controller:

```
    public function savePdf(Request $request)
{

    $destinationPath = 'users/pdf';
    $fileuploadedpath = '';
    $pdf = $request->get('pdf_file');
    if ($pdf != '') {
        $extension = $pdf->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
        $success[0] = $pdf->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $fileuploadedpath = url($destinationPath . "/" . $fileName);
    }

    dd($fileuploadedpath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can save the data URI in the database as a string and then fetch it with **axios**

**This is how you get the URI string:**

```js
doc.output('datauri')
```

Comment: This return me string like `data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYX ...`

Comment: What to do with this string?

Comment: Just save it in your database using PHP for instance...
Once that's done you can show the PDF on website with: `<object data="{the data uri}" type="application/pdf"></object>`

Comment: How to get image url in controller side. Can you edit my controller?

Comment: probably this way: `echo $_GET["pdf_file"]` if not... you would have to do some digging... That's all I could help